# Does ProtoBuf support Polymorphism?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a service which can return a result or null, so I'm defining it as:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package package;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service A {
    rpc getById (ASearchRequest) returns (AResponse) {
    }

    rpc getById (ASearchRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {

    }
}

message AResponse {
    string _id = 1;
    string key = 2;
    string name = 3;
}

message ASearchRequest {
    required string id = 1;
}
```

But the compiler won't execute it, so how to handle the nullable response type in ProtoBuf?

Comment: This question needs a better title.  Nullable type != Polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be to define a message `AnOptionalResponse` that contains a single optional member of type `AResponse`.  Then, return `AnOptionalResponse`, which is either an empty message or a message that contains the optional `AResponse` proto member.

Or just make all the fields in `AResponse` optional.